# Cannot connect (null) error in a gis application

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, gis

I'm trying to use QgsMapCanvas() in my pyggis script but I don't get the result I want getting this message instead:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::repaintRequested() to QgsMapCanvas::refresh()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::screenUpdateRequested() to QgsMapCanvas::updateMap()
```

I exactly followed the instructions from http://geospatialdesktop.com/2009/02/creating_a_standalone_gis_application_1/ and I thing I've done everything right. Do I need to do something else?

The environment variable:
PATH:

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\msys\bin;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Python27;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python\qgis;C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\bin;
```

PYTHONPATH:

```
E:\Python\GeoDjango\myplanet;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\python;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Python27\lib;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Python27\DLLs;
```

QT_PLUGIN_PATH:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\apps\Qt4\plugins
```

Comment: Are you sure you have all the environment variables and paths set correctly for PyQt and QGIS?

Comment: I put the environment variables in the question

Comment: Is QGISHOME also set correctly?

Comment: No, what should I do ?

Comment: If you set QGISHOME to C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera what happens?

Comment: I am trying to duplicate this setup, and seeing a version incompatibility problem between QGIS and the SIP version that comes with the PyQt Windows installer. Trying to import qgis at the Python command line,  I get "RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.1 but the qgis.core module requires API v8.1". I don't yet have a solution, but maybe solving this incompatibility will help?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to follow the steps given in the link you gave:

- [Creating a Standalone GIS Application](http://geospatialdesktop.com/2009/02/creating_a_standalone_gis_application_1/)

I've followed the tutorial in my `Ubuntu` setup and it worked as intended when I completed each step.

There might be two possible causes for the error you get:

- You didn't setup the environment correctly by following the tutorial
- The required `Python` packages might be incompatible in `Windows` or a similar issue related to `Windows`

**Suggetions:** If you are not required to use `Windows` as your development environment for `Python`, I'd suggest installing an OS in the `Linux` family it's much easier and you'll have a lot less headaches.